# Connection in San Salvador, can I leave the airport and do some sightseeing?

Tags: transit, sightseeing

I am travelling from Montevideo, UY to New York.

I have a connection in San Salvador, I arrive there at 1.30 pm and the flight to JFK leaves at 7.45 pm.

I have the B2 tourist visa to enter the US. 
1) Am I allowed leave the aiport? 
2) How far is the aiport from something worth going?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what this question is asking.  Is it asking:
a) Am I permitted from a visa perspective to leave the airport?
B) What are the transportation options between San Salvador airport and the city center?
c) What are sight-seeing recommendations for San Salvador?
Can you please re-word your question so that the intent of your question is clearer?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. I am asking point A and B. I will re word the question.

Comment: In order to answer question 1, one would need to know your country of citizenship.  Question 2 can not be answered on this forum as questions which construct tour itineraries are off topic.  See https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions for help for additional details.

Comment: You US visa is irrelevant for this question. What you need to ask, better on another questions, is: Are citizens of *insert nationality here* allowed to enter Salvador?